# Using a C# Windows DLL in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, mvvm

I have a VS2012 Express (Desktop) MVVM project, where the Model (EF5 Code First) classes are stored in an independent C# DLL.

I am now planning on accessing parts of the same database over the internet using ASP.NET (with which I have much less experience than with programming for Windows). I am therefore creating an ASP.NET View which will use the same Model and VM.

Can I simply use the same DLL in my ASP.NET project, or am I more limited with the code that will run in ASP.NET compared with a Windows DLL?

Comment: You can use that DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're running in Medium Trust (which is highly discouraged), code running in ASP.Net can load any DLL it wants.  (including P/Invoke)
It's all the same .Net; the only difference is whether it's running in an interactive session or in IIS.

Note that running UI code will break things.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same DLL from ASP.Net should not be a problem, But Im wondering how can you use the VideModel code in ASP.Net, None of the property change notification mechanism of ViewModel (Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged) will not be supported in your ASP page.